# Motivic vs Deligne cohomology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, kt.k-theory-and-homology, motives, hodge-theory, motivic-cohomology

Where can I find the construction of the cycle class map from motivic cohomology to Deligne cohomology of smooth projective varieties over the complex numbers?

It should be a construction by Bloch using his cycle complex, but it seems I can't find on the web any paper spelling it out.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The existence of a *cycle class map*  from motivic cohomology is a general fact to every cohomology satisfying certain axioms. For example, to every *mixed Weil theory* in the terminology of Cisinski-Déglise (see [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870811003823), [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/0712.3291) the arXiv preprint) or more generally to every cohomology represented by a spectrum satisfying certain axioms (cf *Theorem* in the Introduction [here](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-the-institute-of-mathematics-of-jussieu/article/the-rigid-syntomic-ring-spectrum/F7CC2419296F69BF10AB77A1FB43B21C), preprint [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1211.5065)). As you see, for these results you need your cohomology to be given by a spectrum in Voevodsky's stable homotopy category. The Deligne cohomology is known to be given by a spectrum, thanks to Holmstrom-Scholbach in [this paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/jag/2015-24-04/S1056-3911-2015-00648-8/) (preprint [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1012.2523)). The cycle class map and the Chern character for Deligne cohomology are defined in Definition 3.7 of Holmstrom-Scholbach.

If you are interested in the computation that such maps coincide with the classic definition, you should also check [this paper](https://academic.oup.com/jtopol/article-abstract/3/2/229/1148105?redirectedFrom=fulltext) by Riou (preprint [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/0907.2710)). In Definition 6.2.3.9. and Remark 6.2.3.10. Riou shows that the canonical map in spectra from $K$-theory spectrum to Beilinson's motivic cohomology spectrum composed with the canonical isomorphism to the Eilenberg-McLane spectrum with rational coefficients coincides with the classical Chern character.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to the papers mentioned, I would like to add Kerr, Lewis, Müller-Stach, *The Abel–Jacobi map for higher Chow groups*, Compositio (2006). They give an explicit construction (if you like that sort of thing -- I do), using currents, mapping a cubical Bloch complex to a complex computing Deligne cohomology. There is also a follow up paper by the first two authors (with obvious title) in Inventiones.

Answer (score 3):

Some alternative references, maybe more classical (and with cycles):

- Section 12.3.3 of vol I of C. Voisin: Hodge theory and complex algebraic geometry. Cambridge studies in advanced mathematics 76. Cambridge University Press 2002.
- Section 7 of H. Esnault and E. Viehweg: Deligne-Beilinson cohomology. In: Beilinson's conjectures on special L-values. Eds. M. Rapoport, P. Schneider, N. Schappacher. Perspectives in Math. 4, Academic Press 1988, pp. 43-91.

Comment: Neither of those deal with motivic cohomology.

Comment: @abx: true, these are only on classical Chow groups, only the $H^{2n,n}$ part of motivic cohomology. Still might be useful to have the references...