# Beilinson regulators and Bloch's mythological algebraic intermediate Jacobians

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, kt.k-theory-and-homology, motives, hodge-theory, motivic-cohomology

In [the paper introducing his motivic cycle complexes](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0001870886900812), Bloch outlines a project he says he was going to return to in the future:

Towards the end of page 270, he says, given a smooth projective variety $X$ over a field $k$:

> The regulator which Beilinson defines using Chern classes, should be replaced by an *Abel-Jacobi* map $\text{CH}^r(X,n)\to J$, where $J$ is the intermediate Jacobian associated to the Hodge structure $H^{2r-1}(X\times\Delta^n, X\times S^{n-1})$ ($S^{n-1}$ being the union of the $n-1$ faces in $\Delta^n$).

**Questions:**

**(1)** Has this actually been done in some later paper by Bloch or anybody else?

**(2)** What does he mean by "Hodge structure associated to $H^{2r-1}(X\times\Delta^n, X\times S^{n-1})$"?

What even is $H^{2r-1}(X\times\Delta^n, X\times S^{n-1})$?

I can imagine a few possibilities, but I'd like to get some insight from someone who has been acquainted with this for longer than I have.

Comment: Dear random-string, (1) I'm not aware of any published work that follows exactly this path. The closest thing may be the paper of Kerr et. al. in my answer to your previous question. (2) It's cohomology of the pair in the sense of algebraic topology. It carries a mixed Hodge structure by Deligne.

Comment: For convenience, the previous question is here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/289898/motivic-vs-deligne-cohomology